# Convert character string and data frame into another data frame

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

I have a one row data frame that looks like this:

```
            Donor  Treatment Timepoint
  MK434_016   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
```

And a character string which looks like this:

```
[1] "AAACAAGCAAACAAGAATTCGGTT-1" "AAACAAGCAAACAATCATTCGGTT-1" "AAACAAGCAAACCTGAATTCGGTT-1" "AAACAAGCAAACTTGGATTCGGTT-1"
[5] "AAACAAGCAAAGACCCATTCGGTT-1" "AAACAAGCAAAGGTAAATTCGGTT-1"
```

I'd like to merge the two to create a data frame that looks like this:

```
                           Donor  Treatment Timepoint
AAACAAGCAAACAAGAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
AAACAAGCAAACAATCATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
AAACAAGCAAACCTGAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
etc...
```

I've tried merging them in several different ways using rbind() or paste() but can't figure out how to get the full data frame I'm looking for.

Comment: It's not clear how your dataset and your character string relate. To bind rows you need a similar structure, to join as new columns you need a matching column (id) on both. Try to explain better how these relate.

Comment: I'm trying to create a data frame that has the same data for each row as the 1 row data frame, just with the various cell barcodes for the row names.

Comment: Welcome to stackpverflow. It looks like you just want to replace your `rownames(`, from MK_434_016, to the respective AAA etc. So `rownames(my_transplant_df) <- my_string_vector_cell_barcodes`

Comment: First you need to repeat your 1-row data frame to have as many rows as in your character string, `your_df = your_df[rep(1, length(your_char_string)), ]` and then you need to set the row names to be your character string, `rownames(your_df) = your_char_string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll first join them together *without* row names, as some tools honor them, some ignore them, and some actively remove them.

```r
df2 <- cbind(df1[rep(1, length(strings)),], data.frame(barcode = strings))
df2
#             Donor  Treatment Timepoint                    barcode
# MK434_016     WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr AAACAAGCAAACAAGAATTCGGTT-1
# MK434_016.1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr AAACAAGCAAACAATCATTCGGTT-1
# MK434_016.2   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr AAACAAGCAAACCTGAATTCGGTT-1
# MK434_016.3   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr AAACAAGCAAACTTGGATTCGGTT-1
# MK434_016.4   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr AAACAAGCAAAGACCCATTCGGTT-1
# MK434_016.5   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr AAACAAGCAAAGGTAAATTCGGTT-1
```

From here, if you really want to remove the `barcode` info from the columns and make them row names, it is simple enough:

```r
rownames(df2) <- df2$barcode
df2$barcode <- NULL
df2
#                            Donor  Treatment Timepoint
# AAACAAGCAAACAAGAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAACAATCATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAACCTGAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAACTTGGATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAAGACCCATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAAGGTAAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
```

A quick `dplyr` version:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1[rep(1, length(strings)),] %>%
  `rownames<-`(NULL) %>%
  mutate(barcode = strings) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames("barcode")
#                            Donor  Treatment Timepoint
# AAACAAGCAAACAAGAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAACAATCATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAACCTGAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAACTTGGATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAAGACCCATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
# AAACAAGCAAAGGTAAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
```

---

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Donor = "WT5", Treatment = "ST002_50uM", Timepoint = "6hr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = "MK434_016")
strings <- c("AAACAAGCAAACAAGAATTCGGTT-1", "AAACAAGCAAACAATCATTCGGTT-1", "AAACAAGCAAACCTGAATTCGGTT-1", "AAACAAGCAAACTTGGATTCGGTT-1", "AAACAAGCAAAGACCCATTCGGTT-1", "AAACAAGCAAAGGTAAATTCGGTT-1")
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. Replicating the df to equal the length of my character string was what I was missing.

Comment: Side note, you can reduce the base solution to `data.frame(df1[rep(1, length(strings)),], row.names=strings)` by using `data.frame` instead of `cbind`.

Comment: It's also a merge operation - `merge(df1, list(barcode=strings), by=NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Using data as in @r2evans' answer

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  reframe(barcode = strings, across(everything()))
#>                      barcode Donor  Treatment Timepoint
#> 1 AAACAAGCAAACAAGAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
#> 2 AAACAAGCAAACAATCATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
#> 3 AAACAAGCAAACCTGAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
#> 4 AAACAAGCAAACTTGGATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
#> 5 AAACAAGCAAAGACCCATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
#> 6 AAACAAGCAAAGGTAAATTCGGTT-1   WT5 ST002_50uM       6hr
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>